# Error when trying to lazy load feature modules using angular-cli with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading, angular-cli

Hi I'm trying to use angular-cli with webpack (+productivity) to build my angular2 app but I'm having issues when trying to lazy load modules which were working with version beta.10...

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "angular2-cookie": "1.2.3",
    "core-js": "2.4.0",
    "material-design-icons": "2.2.3",
    "material-design-lite": "1.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.2.30",
    "@types/protractor": "1.5.16",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-4",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-coverage": "1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.0"
  }
}
```

angular-cli.json

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack",
    "name": "my-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "index": "index.html",
      "root": "src",
      "mobile": false,
      "scripts": [
        "polyfills.ts",
        "../node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js"
      ],
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
        "../node_modules/material-design-lite/material.css"
      ],
      "assets": "assets",
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "config/protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "config/karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  }
}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from "./404.component";
import {AuthenticationGuard} from "./base/security";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/modules/home/home.module#HomeModule' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {routing} from "./app.routes";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from "./404.component";
import {CoreModule} from "./core";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    CoreModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

modules/home/home.routes.ts

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './home.component';

import {AuthenticationGuard} from '../../base/security';

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] }
]);
```

modules/home/home.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BaseModule} from '../../base/base.module';
import {routing} from './home.routes';
import {HomeComponent} from './home.component';
import {NavigationMenuComponent} from '../../base/components';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    BaseModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    NavigationMenuComponent
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

console error message:
[image: Console Error Message]

Is there anything I'm forgetting here? I wasn't able to find any documentation anywhere on how to proceed with this... 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Project structure you provided doesn't contain folder `home` in folder `app/modules`, as a matter of fact, there's no file `home.module` at all, so when you go to route `/home`, there's no module to load: `{ path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/modules/home/home.module#HomeModule' }`. You can't load something that doesn't exist. (at least based on project structure picture you provided)

Comment: Its not being displayed because the folder isn't opened, but its there. I will update the image

Comment: Have you tried `{ path: 'home', loadChildren: 'src/app/modules/home/home.module#HomeModule' }`? (I added `src` to path)

Comment: I'm getting the same error and have posted the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39493782/616304
No replies yet but nice to know I'm not the only one getting this :-(

Answer (score 5):

There's a loader for this ([angular2-router-loader](https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular2-router-loader)). However you can't use it with the CLI without hacking the config. Luckily, `es6-promise-loader` does work with the CLI out-of-the-box.

This is what worked out for me:

First we'll need the es6-promise-loader:

`npm i --save-dev es6-promise-loader`

Then define your route like this:

`{path:"lazy", loadChildren: () => require('es6-promise!./path/to/module')('ClassName')}`

the `es6-promise-loader` replaces the above with this:

```
loadChildren: () => new Promise(function (resolve) {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
          resolve(require('./path/to/module')['ClassName']));
        });
      });
```

which is the proper way to load a module with webpack, but cumbersome to put into every route.

Answer (score 2):

Angular-cli  changed the build system between beta.10 and beta.14, from SystemJS to Webpack.

I tried using lazy loading with angular-cli(beta.17) and it worked for me.

As per my understanding,

**SystemJs** -  we need to give *full path* for lazy loading Ex: **./app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule**

**Webpack** - we need to give *relative path* for lazy loading Ex: **./dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule**

Note : Don't forget to restart the server to see the changes reflecting.(ng serve)

This minor observation fixed my issue. Please see if this is useful or correct me on anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution :

on your app.routers.ts create a function like that :

```
let loadAoTModule = (path, module) => {

  let result = () => new Promise(function (resolve) {
    (require as any).ensure([], function (require: any) {
      resolve(require(path)[module]);
    });
  });

  return result;
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'customer', pathMatch: 'full'},

  { path          : 'customer'  ,
    // for a file locate on 'src/app/customer/customer.module'
    // and a module 'CustomerModule'
    loadChildren  :  loadAoTModule('./customer/customer.module', 'CustomerModule')

  }
];
```

work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `import` to load the module dynamically. Remember to add `"module": "esNext",` in the tsconfig file.

```
loadChildren: () => import('projects/Reservation/src/app/app.module').then((m: any) => m.AppModule),
```

`AppModule` is the class name of the module.