# Lazy loading in Angular2 RC7 and angular-cli webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I have created a new app using `ng new` but when I try to configure a module to load using lazy loading I keep getting an error that the module cannot be found.

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'app/home/home.module'
```

### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-4",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
```

- angular2 RC7
- angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-4
- node: 6.5.0
- os: win32 x64

### app.routing.ts:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: `home`,
    loadChildren: `app/home/home.module`
}];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid but I tried various options and nothing has worked so far.  Given my configuration, am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance,
Stephen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With RC7, you can do as follow:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule',
  }
];
```

Don't forget the "**#**"

Then kill ng serve and restart it

It will works with angular-cli@webpack

P.S: The angular convention is to prefix lazy loaded folders with a (+) e.g. +home/

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me. Killing ng serve and restarting it is crucial for it to work. It'll give errors about not finding the module until you restart ng serve.

Comment: i had same problem.  I also had a relative path in value for loadChildren (coming from Angular2 SystemJs configuration).  I got it working using Khosro's approach AND making the path 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule' instead of './home/home.module#HomeModule'

Comment: It worked for me but, in my case, I had to make the path './home/home.module#HomeModule'); exporting the module with 'export class HomeModule { }' rather than 'export default class HomeModule { }'.

Comment: This also worked for me, but I had to do ```rm -rf /node_modules /tmp``` and then run ```npm install```. It was the only way.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is not present in RC7 anymore.**

```
{path:"lazy", loadChildren: 'app/path/to/module#Class'}
```

will work.

---

The mechanism you are using is still systemjs based. I couldn't make it work with webpack using the "path#class" syntax. So we `require` the module directly:

First we'll need the es6-promise-loader:

`npm i --save-dev es6-promise-loader`

Then define your route like this:

`{path:"lazy", loadChildren: () => require('es6-promise!./path/to/module')('ClassName')}`

the es6-promise-loader replaces the above with this:

```
loadChildren: () => new Promise(function (resolve) {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
          resolve(require('./path/to/module')['ClassName']));
        });
      });
```

which is the proper way to load a module with webpack, but cumbersome to put into every route.

Comment: Is this the recommended approach from the Angular team? I can't find any docs that support this...

Comment: I couldn't find any docs that would reveal the secret of lazy-loading with webpack. If you look at the stack trace, the "path#class" lazy-loading mechanism is clearly designed for SystemJS. This is the only working approach I know.

Comment: "path#class" isn't in the trace although I have tried this as well.  Not sure where the issue lies though, is it Angular RC7 (Doubtful) or Angular-Cli or Webpack?

Comment: There's a loader for webpack (https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular2-router-loader), but you won't be able to use it with angular-cli without hacking the config. es6-promise-loader works with the CLI out-of-the-box.

Comment: check this stack-trace http://i.stack.imgur.com/u0s8z.png for over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492299/error-when-trying-to-lazy-load-feature-modules-using-angular-cli-with-webpack/39496473#39496473. It's using `SystemJsNgModule-loader` which doesn't seem to fit our needs.

Comment: Also, what those loaders do is basically replacing the `path#Class` syntax with a function that's similar to what I posted in my answer. Sorry for the spam.

Comment: @j2L4e Re. angular2-router-loader Vs angular-cli, as of now it seems that it also supports AOT: see [Loader options (AoT compilation)](https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular-router-loader/blob/master/docs/options.md#loader-options-aot-compilation)