# Error: Cannot find module 'app/MyComponent/MyComponent.module' Error: Cannot find module

Tags: angular, webpack

this very similar to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396839/exception-uncaught-in-promise-error-cannot-find-module-app-home-home-modul) but every solution provided by in comments or answer did not solve my issue. Wanted to see if there is anything else i should look at. I tried different paths like

- ./app/mycomponent/mycomponent.module#MyComponentModule,
- .mycomponent//mycomponent.module#MyComponentModule

but nothing works. The biggest difference between mine and the original issue is, we recently added webpack and that's when the application broke. When we did not use any bundling service(webpack) and everything was individual files, it all worked just fine. 
Also my home.module which is the home page doesn't have this issue. Every other pages or modules throw the exact same issue. There is literally not much difference between the home and other modules in terms of implementation.

my **routing module** has this

```
{
    path: 'mycomponent',
    loadChildren: 'app/mycomponent/mycomponent.module#MyComponentModule'
}
```

Full exception below

> bootstrap:51 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find
>   module 'app/mycomponent/mycomponent.module' Error: Cannot find module
>   'app/mycomponent/mycomponent.module'
>       at browser.es5.js:91
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:392)
>       at Object.onInvoke (animations.es5.js:7)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
>       at Zone.run (zone.js:142)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (animations.es5.js:7)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
>       at browser.es5.js:91
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:392)
>       at Object.onInvoke (animations.es5.js:7)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
>       at Zone.run (zone.js:142)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (animations.es5.js:7)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (animations.es5.js:7)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)

**below is my webpack config**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {   entry: './src/main.ts',  
devtool: 'source-map',  
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loaders: ['ts-loader'],
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html|css)$/, 
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: /\.async\.(html|css)$/
      }
    ]   },   
 resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]   },   
 output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')    } };
```

- angular : 4.3.6
- typescript:  2.9.2

Comment: can you try this     loadChildren: 'src/app/mycomponent/mycomponent.module#MyComponentModule'

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi yes. tried that.. did not work.. i tried all different variations :(

Comment: Can you confirm that WebPack is creating the bundles as expected. I think it will create numbered bundles for each lazy module so look for something like `1.bundle.js` in your dist folder.

Comment: We pack is indeed creating bundles but it is just bundles.js not individual chunks. And inside bundles.js I can see my component and its markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else coming here.. I wasn't able to figure out what was the issue with my path.. My teammate got it working..  in routing module.. we changed to

```
import { MyComponentModule } from './myComponentModule/MyComponent.module';
```

then called this class name in the load

```
{
    path: 'myComponent',
    loadChildren: ()=> MyComponentModule
},
```

While this worked, i dont know why the old one did not work even though i gave the exact same path.

Comment: thanks for the solution, it also looks better like that... did you figure out what is causing the error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a relative path from where the *routing module* is located:

```
{
    path: 'mycomponent',
    loadChildren: '../mycomponent/mycomponent.module#MyComponentModule'
}
```

It appears that Angular 6 has changed the requirements so that `loadChildren` must always be relative. I ran into this problem migrating an app to the newer version.

See this change here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f44a2c730a84cd86695d1851395ad28423704bd0

The updated documents say "relative" now.

Comment: Tried. did not work.  I am using angular 4.   update my question with version stack