# Cannot find module "app/pages/pages.module" in angular

Tags: angular, webpack, module

I am new to angular . I am getting error "Cannot find module "app/pages/pages.module" .I searched a lot but still it is coming.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './pages/auth/auth.guard';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path : 'auth' , loadChildren: 'app/pages/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'},
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

My project structure is this :
[project strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNvzP.png)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/41396839/9309209

Comment: i already checked this.But solution given is not working