# Angular 12 lazy loading syntax - what is correct?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am working through an Angular training course (using Angular 12).

```
{ path: 'training', loadChildren: './training/training.module.ts#TrainingModule'},
```

is not working:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find module './training/training.module.ts' ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot find module './training/training.module.ts

I am 100% certain that the path from `app-routing.module.ts`, which contains this code, is correct (I copy/pasted it, to make sure).

However, a previous course (by the same presenter), makes me think that the correct syntax ought to be:

```
{path: 'training', loadChildren: () => import('./training/training.module').then(module => module.TrainingModule)}
```

Why these two possibilities? Are they functionally equivalent? When should I use which?

Comment: The second one is correct, since Angular v6 I think (maybe 8). The first one is the old format.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules (it changed in Angular 8: https://blog.angular.io/version-8-of-angular-smaller-bundles-cli-apis-and-alignment-with-the-ecosystem-af0261112a27#b722).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'app/home/home.module'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396839/exception-uncaught-in-promise-error-cannot-find-module-app-home-home-modul)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lazy loading feature module syntax was changed at some point in major release of angular. In your case (Angular 12) use new syntax.

New syntax is

```
{path: 'training', loadChildren: () => import('./training/training.module').then(module => module.TrainingModule)}
```

and this will work with older anuglar applications

```
{ path: 'training', loadChildren: './training/training.module.ts#TrainingModule'},
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (upvote + answer). The course is labelled Angular 12 on Udemy, but the content makes it clear that it is Angular 2 with some extra stuff inserted to cover breaking changes.