# Angular2 cannot find a nested module

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm working on a web app with two top level modules and several modules under each. Example:

- public

  - registration
  - login
- portal

  - dashboard
  - results
  - appointments

Each of the nested modules has one or more potential routes, services and components. The public and portal modules also have different layout requirements.

What I would like to do is break my code up into modules for each main section above. However, when I attempt to load a module as a child of another route, I get an error stating the module can't be found:

```
error_handler.js:46
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './dashboard/dashboard.module'.
```

Here are my routing files:

```
/app/app.routing.ts

import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const appRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'portal',
    loadChildren: 'portal/portal.module#PortalModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'public/public.module#PublicModule'
  }
]);


/app/portal/portal.routing.ts

import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PortalComponent } from './portal.component';

export const portalRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: PortalComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

The "dashboard" module lives at: /app/portal/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts, but no matter what I set the module path to in `loadChildren`, it can't seem to find it.

What am I doing wrong? I am using WebPack instead of SystemJS.

Comment: can you please add your `systemjs.config.js` file?

Comment: @Supamiu Apologies, I forgot to mention I'm using WebPack

Comment: I don't think the problem come from here, but your portalRouting main path should be an empty path, since 'portal' is already conf in the appRouting

Comment: @NoémiSalaün Sorry, that's just a copy/paste artifact. I've removed the redundant path from the example, but you're correct in that it doesn't affect the functionality. I get the same error.

Comment: Looks like using the es6-promise loader in this example works using webpack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492299/error-when-trying-to-lazy-load-feature-modules-using-angular-cli-with-webpack

Comment: Thanks for solving this problem. I just encountered it and I was extremely frustrated. How did you come up thinking of using the es6-promise-loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the es6-promise loader seems to be working for me so far. Here's my routers to this point...

```
app/app.routing.ts
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const appRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'portal',
    loadChildren: () => require('es6-promise!./portal/portal.module')('PortalModule')
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => require('es6-promise!./public/public.module')('PublicModule')
  }
]);

app/portal/portal.routing.ts
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PortalComponent } from './portal.component';

export const portalRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'portal',
    component: PortalComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => require('es6-promise!./dashboard/dashboard.module')('DashboardModule')
      },
      {
        path: 'results',
        loadChildren: () => require('es6-promise!./results/results.module')('ResultsModule')
      }
    ]
  }
]);

app/portal/dashboard/dashboard.routing.ts
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

export const dashboardRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
]);
```

and I'm seeing the correct output of my `<router-outlet>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

The correct path for the dashboard module will be `app/portal/dashboard/dashboard.module`.

For some reason webpack needs the absolute path in this case. 
Don't forget to restart the server after changing the path.

Comment: I've tried this approach and got the same result. However, if I use the es6-promise loader, it will work as expected.

Comment: Did you restart the server? In my case it only worked after that.

Comment: Yes, and I still got the same result.

Comment: absolute path resolved for me. I guess in module registering the app structure only scrapes first level resources.